# Python Click module, how to take in a username and password as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, click

I've created a very simple CLI application that takes in a username and password as arguments using Click. Using `@click.password_option()` I'm able to mask the password and have the user confirm their password without any code from my end, which is great.

Though, I noticed that the `email` field is being slurped in as `None`. I believe this is because I am using `password.option()`

Does anyone have a workaround for this? I've tried using Click's `Context.invoke()` and `Context.forward()` to pass in the email field but that was no help.

```
@cli.command()
@click.argument("email", type=str, required=True)
@click.password_option()
def register(email, password):
        click.echo(f"{email} {password}")
```

```
Output:
> None test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works as expected

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument("email", type=str, required=True)
@click.password_option()
def register(email, password):
        click.echo(f"{email} {password}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

```sh
$ python3 example.py foo@bar.com
$ Password:
$ Repeat for confirmation:
foo@bar.com test
```